# Mobile Keyboard customization for game on unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm developing a game for mobile devices, where i add inputfileds for login and register. Everything is perfectly fine but when i touch on input-field to write text like(Username, password) the keyboards pops-up perfectly.

Issue: Keyboard is every large in size. I want to change height of the keyboard or should is there any approach to customize the look of keyboard??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.
When you are developing a native iOS app, you can define a lot of keyboard options. But there is no keyboard API that allows you to show/listen or customize the keyboard.

My advice would be to make the best of suggested Unity options.

Comment: Noted. Thanks alot (:

Comment: And one more thing, do I off the keyboard suggestions column from unity? Or this can not change from mobile settings?